# Calculating the Maximum Likelihood Estimate

Tags: maximum-likelihood

I'm trying to understand MLE, but struggling with a question/example, so was hoping for an explanation if someone can help.

There's a ring toss game which is repeated until it's succeeds for the first time. Each time the game is played, it succeeds with the probability p; and each attempt is independent.

I have the following probability function of X.
$\ f(x)=p(1−p)^{x-1}$

I'm trying to work out the MLE of p (given a single observation x of X). Would someone know how to go about this?
What I'm struggling with here is that the number of attempts, as it isn't fixed and instead is just 'n'.

Answer (score 3):

Your likelihood function is
$$
L(p \mid x) = p \left(1 - p\right)^{x - 1}.
$$
Differentiating with respect to $p$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d L}{d p}(p \mid x)
&= \left(1 - p\right)^{x - 1} - p (x - 1) \left(1 - p\right)^{x - 2} \\
&= (1 - p)\left(1 - p\right)^{x-2} -  (p x - p) \left(1 - p\right)^{x - 2} \\
&=  (1 - p - p x + p) \left(1 - p\right)^{x - 2} \\
&=  (1 - p x) \left(1 - p\right)^{x - 2}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Setting this equal to zero (since the derivative of $L(p \mid x)$ at $p$ is zero if $L(p \mid x)$ is at a maximum), we get
$$
(1 - p x) \left(1 - p\right)^{x - 2} = 0.
$$
Assuming $p < 1$, it follows that $\left(1 - p\right)^{x - 2} \neq 0$, so $1 - p x = 0$, and hence $p = 1 / x$.
Thus, the maximum likelihood estimate of $p$ is
$$
\hat{p} = \frac{1}{x}.
$$

Comment: You should avoid giving out questions to homework questions.  Instead, consider giving hints.

Comment: In general, for multiple realizations of $X$, the likelihood should involve a product, and thus, the log likelihood will involve a sum. Writing down the log of the likelihood function prior to differentiating will make things much easier...

Comment: @compbiostats the question says "given a single observation x of X"

Comment: Even with one observation, the likelihood is still a product of two terms in $p$, so maximising the log-likelihood is simpler.

Comment: @ArtemMavrin Whoops... I see that now :) I've edited my previous comment to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks, that matches what one of mates told me the answer was. That makes senses now seeing the working out.

Comment: @Ben sure, but this case is so easy there's no need to take logs in my opinion

Comment: Agree - either method is fine in this case.

Comment: Just to improve this answer, may I recommend that you use $\hat{p}$ to denote the estimator, rather than $p$.  Also, it would be worth flagging what happens to the MLE when $x=0$, since in that case, your expression for the estimator is undefined.

Comment: @StatsStudent I think sometimes it’s useful to see an entire answer worked out so that you can learn how to approach similar problems

Comment: @ArtemMavrin Thanks for showing it worked out. Really obvious now seeing this, and I can see where I was going wrong as I was just over complicating it in my attempts

Comment: I agree.  But surely this isn't the student's first time being introduced to the material.  The OP didn't even attempt to comply with the site's self-study "policies" by telling you what he/she has tried.  Not a big deal.  Just keep it in mind for future homework questions.

Comment: @Ben thanks for the suggestion for using $\hat{p}$! Regarding the $x = 0$ case: I don't think that's possible given the wording of the question. I interpreted $x$ as the number of trials until a success (including the success) which makes $x$ at least $1$

Comment: @StatsStudent thank you for the feedback. I will keep that in mind in the future

Comment: @Artem Mavrin: I think you're right about $x$ - I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a single observation, you have $n=1$.  So the [likelihood function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function) for the observed data is:

$$L_x(p) = p(1-p)^{x-1} \quad \quad \quad \text{for all } 0 \leqslant p \leqslant 1.$$

As the name suggests, the [maximum-likelihood estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) is the value that maximises the likelihood function:

$$\hat{p}(x) = \underset{0 \leqslant p \leqslant 1}{\text{arg max }} L_x(p)$$

In this particular case, this is just a basic calculus problem, where you are trying to maximise the likelihood function with respect to a continuous argument variable.  Since the likelihood function is a product of non-negative parts that depend on $p$, it is usual to find the maximising value by maximising the log-likelihood function (i.e., the logarithm of the likelihood function).  If you apply standard calculus methods to maximise this function, you will be able to derive the maximum-likelihood estimator $\hat{p}$.